# How to calculate the number of instances of variable by quarter of year for multiple years in Power BI?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I have a column where an occurrence is marked by 1 and non-occurrence marked by 0. I want to get a running total of the number of occurrences by quarter for each year in my data, such that by the end of quarter 4, I will have the full total of the year (which means that by the end of quarter 2 I would have the total occurrences for the first half of the year). I want the count of the running total to begin at zero for each new year.

My data looks like this:

```
Team Event Date Year Quarter Task_Completed Tasks_open 
 A   1/24/2018  2018 1        0              1 
 A   5/23/2018  2018 2        0              1 
 A   6/25/2018  2018 2        0              1 
... 
 A   1/23/2019  2019 1        1              0 
 A   1/24/2019  2019 1        1              0  
 A   4/3/2019   2019 2        1              0 
 A   4/4/2019   2019 2        0              1
```

I would want it to look like this:

```
Team  Year  Quarter   Tally_of_completed   Tally_of_incomplete 
A      2018  1          0                     1 
A      2018  2          0                     3 
... 
A      2019  1          2                     0 
A      2019  2          3                     1
```

I have tried using this expression and it successfully works, but only gets me the counts for year 2019.

```
Completed Count = 
var selected_month = date(year(today()), month(today()), 1) 
var selected_3_months = date(year(today()), month(today())-3, 1) 
return CALCULATE(SUM('my_table'[completed_number]), 
       FILTER(ALL('my_table'[Event Date]), 'my_table'[Event Date] < 
              selected_month), 'my_table'[Event Date] >= selected_3_months)
```

I have tried changing the first part of the expression from `date(year(today()), month(today()), 1)` to `date(year('my_data'[Event Date']), month('my_data'[event date]), 1)`. This did not produce any values, but also did not throw any errors.

I've tried looking for a solution online, but am not successful. Would really appreciate some insight or a link to a truly helpful resource.

Comment: Do you have a date table/calendar dimension?

Comment: I am not sure how your data model but I will try my best. You can create in case you already have an active relation another relation (it will be marked as inactive) and use `userelationship(...)`. Also for counting the non-ocurrence you might have to use `count(...)`.

Comment: I do not have a date table, but the 'Event Date' field in my data set is a date field. Are you suggesting that I create a separate date table and then join it to my data? I am not sure what to do after that thought....could you give a more detailed example of how to use count()? When I tried that before, it gave a total count for the column in every row and I am looking for a count by quarter in each year.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how your data model is but it might want to look like this,

[image: Calendar]

Don't forget to mark you `Date` as `date`

[image: Mark as date]

A basic and may not sufficent calendar can look like this

[image: Calendar_table]

To make a calendar with `DAX` you can google it and there are tons of references. At this point you probably can "slice and dice" your events. Then try,

```
Tally_of_completed = SUM('my_table'[completed_number])
```

and non-completed

```
Tally_of_incomplete = CALCULATE(COUNT('my_table'[completed_number]);'my_table'[completed_number]=0)
```

Note that the delimiter can be different. Then drag and drop `Quarter` field in a `slicer` visual...

**EDIT**

If you have installed one of the lastest `Power BI` versions you will have this date hierarchy that may help you.

[image: Date_hierarchy]